# How to pass/escape an argument to an event handler attached using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, escaping

In the code HTML+Script below,

- an event handler is attached after page load using `setAttribute(...)`.
- The event handler is passed an argument which is read dynamically too.
- the event handler is attached successfully ( verified by a `getAttribute(...)`

However, the handler does not fire.

What is wrong with the snippet below?

```
<HTML>
 <BODY onload="loader();">
   <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td id="myId">FirstColumn</td>
                <td id="otherId">SecondColumn</td>
                <td id="lastId">Balderdash</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
   </table>
 </BODY>
 <script language="javascript">
    function loader(){
        
    document.getElementById('myId').setAttribute('onmouseover','showMessage("'+document.getElementById('otherId').innerHTML+'");');
    alert(document.getElementById('myId').getAttribute('onmouseover'));

    document.getElementById('myId').setAttribute('onmouseout','alert(\"'+document.getElementById('otherId').innerHTML+'\");');
    alert(document.getElementById('myId').getAttribute('onmouseout'));
    document.getElementById('lastId').setAttribute('onmouseout','alert("hohoho");');
    
    alert(document.getElementById('lastId').getAttribute('onmouseout'));
    function showMessage( aMessage ){
        alert(aMessage);
    }
 </script>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tim's post up there helped me figure it out; albeit my understanding is empirical.

In addition to making a direct assignment

e.g.

```
document.getElementById(...).onMouseOver = stuff;
function stuff(){//do the Deed};
```

in lieu of

```
document.getElementById(...).setAttribute(...);
```

Apparently the event handler attached **may not** accept any argument.

I changed my handler signatures to accept 0 arguments, and it works!

Comment: No, in non-IE browsers your event handler functions will be passed an event object, which can be extremely useful. In IE you have to access the event via window.event. For example: el.onmouseover = function(evt) { evt = evt || window.event; /* Do stuff with event object */ };

Comment: Ty (+: that is useful

At the moment we're looking purely at IE though

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `setAttribute` to set event handlers on DOM nodes. Just use the event handler property direct, and assign it a function rather than a string:

```
document.getElementById('myId').onmouseover = function() {
  showMessage(document.getElementById('otherId').innerHTML);
};
```

Comment: Two questions - 
- IIRC the handler doesn't have to be an anonymous function; y/n?
- Doesn't the argument passed need to be escaped?

Comment: Correct, the handler does not have to be an anonymous function. Second, I didn't focus so much on the escaping part of the question, but I assume that bit's no longer a problem?