# Creating a button dynamically with arguments for onclick

Tags: javascript, dom-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to pass arguments to an event handler function and still use ‘this’ reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202339/how-to-pass-arguments-to-an-event-handler-function-and-still-use-this-referenc)

I've done a bit of searching but I'm struggling to find a solution to this.

Anyway:

```
function CreateMe(){

    //....

    var mycell = row.insertCell(-1);
    var myelement3 = document.createmyelement("input");
    myelement3.type = "button";
    myelement3.value = "Delete";
    myelement3.onclick = DeleteMe;
    myelement3.name = "Delete[]";
    mycell.appendChild(myelement3);

    //....

}

function DeleteMe(){
    alert(this);
}
```

I have a form with a button that calls `CreateMe` which dynamically creates a button. What I'm after is to be able to pass in arguments to the `DeleteMe` function when this dynamic button is clicked; in particular this:

```
onclick="DeleteMe(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)"
```

from: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/HTML/Deletingtablerows.htm

I'm at a bit of a loss on how to proceed here, so if anybody could lend a hand it would be appreciated.

**Edit**: Just to be clear, what is being asked is how I can pass arguments from the `onclick` event of the dynamically generated button to the `DeleteMe` function. Clearly I am unable to do this as this would simply evaluate the function immediately:

```
    myelement3.value = "Delete";
    myelement3.onclick=DeleteMe(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex);
    myelement3.name = "Delete[]";
```

Comment: Did you ever look into jQuery? It makes your life a LOT easier, aspecially in these kind of situations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass arguments to an event handler function and still use 'this' reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202339/how-to-pass-arguments-to-an-event-handler-function-and-still-use-this-referenc) and also [How to pass/escape an argument to an event handler attached using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470948/how-to-pass-escape-an-argument-to-an-event-handler-attached-using-javascript). I searched for [`javascript event handler pass argument`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+event+handler+pass+argument).

Comment: @Hidde, Ah to be honest I'd really rather not involve something like jQuery. I'm just not too keen on such libraries etc.

Comment: @FelixKling I'm sorry, but I'm not quite seeing how they are possible duplicates as neither of those make any mention of dynamically generated buttons. :S However this is probably my lack of understanding of JS than your fault. ;)

Comment: There a couple of ways to set up event handlers. Have a look at http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html for an comprehensive explanation. The easiest way would be to assign a function to the `onclick` property: `element.onclick = function() {...}`. And how the function could look like can be found in the other two questions ;) **edit**: See, you are nearly there, you just have to do: `myelement3.onclick = function() { DeleteMe(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex); };`, or use `.call` to also set `this` properly if you need it, just as shown in http://stackoverflow.com/q/9202339/218196.

Comment: It does not matter whether the element has been created dynamically or existed in the document from the beginning. All you need is a reference to the DOM element.

Comment: @FelixKling Would you mind posting an answer please so I may accept and close this question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are nearly there. `.onclick` is expected to be a function, so all you have to do is wrap that function call into another function:

```
myelement3.onclick = function() { 
    DeleteMe(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex);
    // or
    // DeleteMe.call(this, this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex);
    // to set `this` inside `DeleteMe` to the DOM element as well.
};
```

If the browser supports [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), you could even do:

```
myelement3.onclick = DeleteMe.bind(
    myelement3, 
    myelement3.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex
);
```

but that would evaluate `myelement3.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex` at the moment of creation and not when the element is clicked. If elements change their position, this could lead to problems, and in this case you'd rather go with the first solution.

---

Alternative, since `this` refers to the clicked element, you can access the row index *inside `DeleteMe`*:

```
function DeleteMe(){
    var index = this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
}

// ...

myelement3.onclick = DeleteMe;
```

This works as long as you call `DeleteMe` only as event handler and not manually.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience and explanation. Merry Christmas! :)

Comment: No problem :) Merry Christmas to you too!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
function DeleteMe(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    var el = e.target || e.srcElement;
    // here el is your button that's been clicked
    alert(el.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex);
}​
```

Comment: What I'm finding difficult is how exactly I setup the onclick part of the dynamically generated button to pass an argument to *DeleteMe*.